# Could this be a plausible way for unicellular organisms to possess intelligence?

Tags: biology, xenobiology

Basically, instead of neurons, the "brain" consists of organelles that can transmit information and thus function like neurons. Of course, this organism is gonna be super huge to contain all that stuff, but we do see gigantic cells in real life.

Is this plausible in any way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by "plausible?" Do you mean in Real Life? Answer is no. Do you mean "to a degree of suspension of disbelief for my imaginary world?" Absolutely! Please remember that our [help/on-topic] states that we help you create imaginary worlds.

Comment: Cells are equivalent to Turing machines  So pretty open ended. However communication is the sticking point. I suspect once organelles are able to do what is needed it probably would be better to describe it as cells in cell architecture. IE wheel reinvention.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, a cell could do most jobs a multicellular organism could. For instance, white blood cells use receptors to detect foreign cells. Also, Stem cells are remarkably well adapted as they can use their surroundings to influence which DNA is used to make proteins. In theory, your cell could be regulated by chemicals (sodium ions for instance) that causes it in ways like the stem cells to react. How it would display this intelligence would be up to you

Answer (score 0):

**Sure**

Just make the *big cell* the same shape as a human brain and have the electrical activity work the same way. Of course nothing like this exists in the real world. Your organism is so unlike existing ones that the equivalent to *neurons* being called *cells* or called *organelles*  is a matter of preference.